# Use Image from desktop as NSImage

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsimage, nsimageview

How can I set a NSImageView's Image to a file from the desktop, not from inside my app.
this is the code i've tried:

```
[applicationIcon setImage:myImage];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a image from desktop to NSImageView.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the image to your project, otherwise, you won't be able to use it.

You might wanna take a look at this documentation
[OSx Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Intro/Intro.html).